# How could I send XML data to a remote ColdFusion server from a .NET client?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, asp.net-mvc, coldfusion-8

I am trying to serialize a form to XML and send it to a ColdFusion server (CF 8). Simple, right? Well, I keep getting an error message saying "ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings." I am definitely not a CF expert, so I'm not sure what to do on the .NET side to fix this issue. The ColdFusion server belongs to a third party company and I have no access to the CF Admin whatsoever. Below is the C# code that I'm using to send the POST request to the ColdFusion server:

```
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index(Transmission t)
        {
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "";
            ViewBag.OtherMessage = "";
            ViewBag.ResponseHtml = "";


            try
            {
                var xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Transmission));
                XmlWriterSettings xws = new XmlWriterSettings();
                XmlSerializerNamespaces ns = new XmlSerializerNamespaces(); ns.Add("", "");
                xws.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;
                using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
                {
                    XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sw, xws);
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(writer, t, ns);
                    var contentData = sw.ToString();
                    var httpContent = new StringContent(contentData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/xml");
                    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
                    httpClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
                    //string httpContentAsString = await httpContent.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync("theUrlToCF", httpContent);
                    ViewBag.ResponseHtml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    return View("Error");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string message = ex.Message;
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
                return View("Error");
            }
        }
```

Please let me know if I can provide any further information. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Update: Output**

```
<Transmission>
   <TransmissionHeader>
      <UserId>1234</UserId>
      <Password>1234</Password>
   </TransmissionHeader>
   <MoveRequest>
      <BillToCode>example</BillToCode>
      <AuthorizationNumber>123456</AuthorizationNumber>
      <Caller>0</Caller>
      <Customer>C</Customer>
      <Cargo>
         <Shipper>
            <Name>example</Name>
            <AddressLine1>123 Sesame St</AddressLine1>
            <City>Tuscaloosa</City>
            <ZipCode>50231</ZipCode>
            <Country>United States</Country>
            <Phone>5555555</Phone>
            <Fax>555</Fax>
            <OpenTime>12:00</OpenTime>
            <CloseTime>17:00</CloseTime>
            <DefaultAirport>example</DefaultAirport>
            <DockHighRequired>false</DockHighRequired>
         </Shipper>
         <Consignee>
            <DockHighRequired>false</DockHighRequired>
         </Consignee>
         <CargoDetails>
            <NumberContainers>0</NumberContainers>
            <Pieces>0</Pieces>
            <WeightOf>0</WeightOf>
            <LengthOf>0</LengthOf>
            <WidthOf>0</WidthOf>
            <HeightOf>0</HeightOf>
            <LooseLoad>false</LooseLoad>
            <Stackable>false</Stackable>
            <Hazmat>false</Hazmat>
            <HazmatUNNumber>0</HazmatUNNumber>
            <CostPerPiece>0</CostPerPiece>
         </CargoDetails>
      </Cargo>
   </MoveRequest>
</Transmission>
```

`Transmission` Class:

```
[Serializable]
    public class Transmission
    {
        public TransmissionHeader TransmissionHeader { get; set; }
        public MoveRequest MoveRequest { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you post an example of the serialized data `contentData`?  It sounds like something in your `Transmission` object is being serialized to an array of bytes.  It might be useful to see the definition of your `Transmission` object too.

Comment: @tgolisch Sure, hang on. I'll update the question with the output.

Comment: @tgolisch The question has been updated. The `Transmission` class is a class that is made up of the other elements you see in the XML, such as `TranmissionHeader` and `Shipper`. I did this to conform to the schema of the third party system to which I'm sending the data.

Comment: Are you really sure...if you put a breakpoint on the `contentData` line and inspect the variable, it has the right value....did you try with https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclientextensions.postasxmlasync(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: @Hackerman Yes, I'm positive that is has the right value. That's why I have no idea why it's breaking.

Comment: "ByteArray objects.." is CF error message. What line it is throwing error in your code? Is it at ViewBag.ResponseHtml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()'? Step through the code and see where it blowing it?

Comment: @RajN I put breakpoints on every line of code inside the Try Catch block and it isn't breaking. My code isn't throwing an exception. Rather, the response I'm getting from the CF server is telling me that there is an error. In my view I am parsing the response HTML and displaying it with `Html.Raw()`.

Comment: Well, then the service at CF end having trouble to parse the input. May be some encoding issue. Try with different encoding values.

Comment: @RajN I have tried with all of the encoding values in the `System.Text.Encoding` class. I am still getting the same error message.

Comment: I'm afraid the issue might be within vendor app, nothing much you can do about it. Good luck.

Comment: the following statement doesn't make any sense.  You are trying to convert a string to html.  Contents is usually a byte array : ViewBag.ResponseHtml = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();  Should be : string results = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Content);

Comment: @jdweng Your proposed change is unnecessary, plus it introduces an error.  Converting a string to html is totally unnecessary, considering that html is a string.

Comment: @tgolisch What would cause something in my `Transmission` object to be serialized to array of bytes?

Comment: (this is a long-shot): Any chance the server doesn't like UTF8?  Could you try UTF7?

Comment: @tgolisch I tried UTF7, as well as all of the different encoding types, but none of them worked. I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Inside of your class definition (or lower/contained classes), are you using any XML attributes like `[XmlArray]`, or any other XML attributes?

Comment: @tgolisch Yes. I am using `[XmlElement(ElementName = "Blah")]` in some cases where I need the XML element to be different than the variable name.

Comment: Has the vendor given you an example of the XML format that they expect to receive?  Sometimes, a slight mismatch will give strange errors.

Comment: @tgolisch Yes. We have extensively reviewed the XML I'm sending and we have verified that it matches their schema.

Comment: At this point, all I can offer you is debug strategy advice: try sending blank strings for some of the fields, to see if you can isolate it to one specific field.

Comment: @tgolisch I will do that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I can explain why, but the issue was that `Content-Type` in the request header was set to `application/xml` when it should have been `text/xml`. I hope this will help someone in the future. Be sure to use Fiddler or some other web debugging software to inspect your HTTP requests to make sure that they look correct if you're having similar issues.